# Problem with booting ubuntu 20.04 after initial install on laptop

Tags: boot, nvidia, 20.04, asus, intel

I installed Linux for the first time today on my laptop. My laptop is a Asus zenbook with an intel i7 processor and nvidia geforce 960m graphics card, not sure about the rest specs but can probably find out if necessary. Also I am **not** dual-booting with windows.

The istallation work fine from usb, the try Linux option worls as well. The problem occurs when I restart the computer after installation and get to the window that says: "Please remove the installation medium and press ENTER", since when I do that I only get a black screen. If I restart my computer after that I only get to a loading screen that says ASUS, which the computer becomes stuck on.

If I instead enter the boot manager by pressing esc while starting the computer I can select the boot devices:

- ubuntu (P4: Micron_M600_MTFDDAV256NBF)
- UEFI OS (P4: Micron_M600_MTFDDAV256NBF)
- ubuntu (P4: Micron_M600_MTFDDAV256NBF).

Which says ubuntu two times. Both of the ubuntu options is not possible to be booted.

I am very grateful for amy response since currently I am only able to access the test Linux option.

Thanks!